# How to detect that a sub widget popped in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a few widgets and I want to implement CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition for each of them. I created a common widget call FullscreenDialog widget passing in the title and body to it. The body param is one of the many widgets I want to appear as an animated dialog rising from the bottom of the screen. Below is the FullscreenDialog code:

```
class FullscreenDialog extends StatefulWidget {
    final Widget title;
    final Widget body;
    const FullscreenDialog({
        super.key,
        required this.title,
        required this.body,
    });

    @override
    State<FullscreenDialog> createState() => _FullscreenDialogState();
}

class _FullscreenDialogState extends State<FullscreenDialog>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    late AnimationController _primary, _secondary;
    late Animation<double> _animationPrimary, _animationSecondary;

    @override
    void initState() {
        _primary = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
        _animationPrimary = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _primary, curve: Curves.easeOut));
        //Secondary
        _secondary = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
        _animationSecondary = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _secondary, curve: Curves.easeOut));
        _primary.forward();
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
        _primary.dispose();
        _secondary.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition(
        primaryRouteAnimation: _animationPrimary,
        secondaryRouteAnimation: _animationSecondary,
        linearTransition: true,
        child: Dismissible(
            direction: DismissDirection.down,
            key: UniqueKey(),
            onDismissed: (_) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: widget.title,
                leading: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -90 * math.pi / 180,
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    onPressed: () {
                    _primary.reverse();
                    // Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    // });
                    },
                ),
                ),
            ),
            body: widget.body,
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
}
```

and here's the widget that builds the title and body of the FullscreenDialog, passing as params:

```
class NameForm extends StatelessWidget {
    const NameForm({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
        String name = '';
    
        return FullscreenDialog(
        title: const Text('Add a Name'),
        body: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: ListView(
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
                TextFormField(
                autofocus: true,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                initialValue: name,
                onChanged: (value) {
                    name = value.trim();
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name',
                    hintText: 'Name',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a name';
                    }
                    return null;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
                ),
                CupertinoButton.filled(
                onPressed: () {
                    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                },
                child: const Text('Add name'),
                ),
            ],
            ),
        ),
        );
    }

}
```

When I load the NameForm it comes up from the bottom of the screen and when I press the down arrow (back button) it slides back down, no problem. However, when I click on CupertinoButton, the form doesn't slide back down, but just vanishes. Not sure how to make it call the primary.reverse on the FullscreenDialog from the NameForm. Or am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code to use class extension rather than passing widgets as parameters. Here's my new FullscreenDialog:

```
class FullscreenDialog extends StatefulWidget {
    const FullscreenDialog({super.key});

    @override
    State<FullscreenDialog> createState() => FullscreenDialogState();
}

class FullscreenDialogState<T extends FullscreenDialog> extends State<T>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    late AnimationController primary, secondary;
    late Animation<double> animationPrimary, animationSecondary;

    @override
    void initState() {
        //Primaty
        primary = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
        animationPrimary = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: primary, curve: Curves.easeOut));
        //Secondary
        secondary = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
        animationSecondary = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: secondary, curve: Curves.easeOut));
        primary.forward();
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
        primary.dispose();
        secondary.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    pop() {
        primary.reverse();
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
    }
}
```

and here's the NameForm widget that extends FullscreenDailog:

```
class NameForm extends FullscreenDialog {
  const NameForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<NameForm> createState() => NameFormState();
}

class NameFormState extends FullscreenDialogState<NameForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    String name = '';

    return CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition(
      primaryRouteAnimation: animationPrimary,
      secondaryRouteAnimation: animationSecondary,
      linearTransition: true,
      child: Dismissible(
        direction: DismissDirection.down,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        onDismissed: (_) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Add new course'),
            leading: Transform.rotate(
              angle: -90 * math.pi / 180,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                onPressed: () {
                  pop();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: ListView(
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  initialValue: name,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    name = value.trim();
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name',
                    hintText: 'Name',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                CupertinoButton.filled(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      pop();
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add name'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is still some repetitive code in here but it works!